# Plot generated with matplotlib doesn't shows up in Yakuake

Tags: python

I'm trying to display the plot of this really simple script:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as mp

mp.plot([0,1,2])
mp.show()
```

In Konsole no problem, an external window pop up with the plot. But nothing shows up with yakuake.

Is it possible to do it? If not, is there a workaround?

Comment: I tested this on my system. The upper script also works in yakuake. So the terminal in yakuake is minimized and an external window pops up. So, it is definitely possible.

Comment: Can you share you're yakuake config? I only get the [……] answer of python. Do you use python default shell?

Comment: You should extend you question with information about the error message. At the moment it is not really reliable that it is a problem concerning yakuake. You could also present your config for yakuake.

Comment: As I said in my answer, it now works.... I cannot say what have changed....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't understand, now it works.

Maybe a reboot was needed after the installation of the python library...